# PHP application works on a Windows server, but it doesn't work on a Linux server, why?

Tags: linux, php

I have a PHP web application. This application works on Windows server, but it doesn't work on a Linux server. I think this is about `php.ini` or file permissions. What can be other reasons for this situaion? What must be the basic `php.ini` configurations for this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  File permissions are often a problem, also directories/files are case-sensitive on Linux make sure any references in php.ini are correct

Comment: doesn't work means that for example,i have a ajax request from a php file but the this file doesnt response anything.This means the server doesnt compile or execute this php file.I have checked the php files' character encoding type and all of them are UTF-8.Sometimes there can be problems when php file is ANSI character encoding type.However this file UTF-8

Comment: Well, that tells us what doesn't happen. What does it do? What do the logs say? Is the right URI being hit? Is it coming back with a 200 response code? It sounds like PHP just isn't installed or enabled.

Comment: `file doesnt response anything.This means the server doesnt compile or execute this php file.` statement in not the truth. The reasons can vary. And server will return at least the code itself. If you can see a php code in the page source of the requested php file - it is the positive proof for 
server doesnt compile or execute this php file" statement. If not - welcome to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never ask "What can be other reasons". We are not weather forecasters here. We are programmers. And we have tools to be **certain**, what particular problem we are experiencing now.

The only thing you need is to ask PHP to tell you, what's the problem.

The easiest way is to put these lines into your configuration file,

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and see what your app will say. It can be permissions or `php.ini`. All will be told.
Quite easy, eh? ;)

If these magic lines won't help, there are several other ways, the manual has a good manual in it:  http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

When your server goes public, don't forget to change these lines to

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and see error messages in the error log, not revealing it to the possible hackers and innocent users.

Comment: I want to ask my question more spesifically.My php pages have somehow converted to ANSI character encoding type while uploading to the server.Is there any way to make the pages work even thaey have ANSI character encoding type?In other way i open all the pages and save them as UTF-8 one by one

Comment: @cubuzoa the file encoding doesn't affect script execution. ANSI or UTF or even 1256 would work as well. And how do you know it has been converted? for the ansi symbols utf-8 has same codes - there is no difference between them

Comment: when i save as the page with notepad there is current encoding type as ANSI

Comment: @cubuzoa well you can choose another encoding when save. But again: encoding doesn't affect script execution. Te script will run being saved in any encoding. Can you run any scripts on your server? Do you have any not interacting with ajax? Do you have any idea what these scripts do? Start debug a little?